# How to bring object out of a for loop

Tags: java, object, for-loop, return

I have the following method that should return a **product** object if its name attribute matches the input string.

```
public Product find(String nameInput){  
 for(Product product : this.Products){           
        if(product.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(nameInput)){
            return product;                        
        }     
   }
}
```

Its giving me the following error:

[image]

I know that I could return null at the end of the method, however is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: There are streams that make the loop one line, but you still need to decide if you want to return null or throw an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) and [findFirst](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--) to return `Optional` with first matching `Product` or empty `Optional`

```
this.Products.stream()
             .filter(p->p.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(nameInput))
             .findFirst();
```

You can also use [orElse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) methods on `Optional` to return default value

Comment: How does it return a product object?

Comment: see this docs https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-streams#referencing `findFirst` is short-circuiting terminal operation and return `Optional` @InitialisingAttributes

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
public Optional<Product> find(String nameInput){  
 for(Product product : this.Products){           
        if(product.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(nameInput)){
            return Optional.of(product)                        
        }     
   }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

or, even better, replace the ForEach loop with a Stream.

then you can use with *ifPresent*

```
  find("Stackoverflow").ifPresent(consumer)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 8 you can return an Optional instead of a Product:

```
public Optional<Product> find(String nameInput){  
  for(Product product : this.Products){           
    if(product.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(nameInput)){
        return Optional.of(product);                        
    }     
  }
  return Optional.empty();
}
```

Additionally, as several other posters also mentioned, I would use the stream api instead of a for each loop.

Answer (score 1):

Do it as follows:

```
public Product find(String nameInput){  
    Product p = null;
    for(Product product : this.Products){           
        if(product.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(nameInput)){
            p = product;
            break;                        
        }     
    }
    return p;
}
```